# Error while casting dataframe column type : scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to cast dataframe column type from 'String' to 'Long' using :

```
df.withColumn("ColName", df.col("ColName").cast(LongType))
```

facing runtime error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:110)

Please help

Comment: Your code works for me for a trivial sample, so more info is needed: can you show some sample data? And which Spark version are you using?

Comment: The content is a String and you're trying to tell it it's a Long, which it'll complain about.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.withColumn("ColName_new", col("ColName").cast(LongType))
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what this does, and why it solves the OPs question.